# React App works fine when run with snack in the browser, but encounters errors when run with expo go on mobile

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new with reactjs and I'm coding with snack. I'm trying to make an app and when I run it on the browser, everything works fine, but when I try it on Expo Go on my mobile device, the app either crashes entirely or shows this error

> Text strings must be rendered within a < Text > component

I'm not really sure what's wrong with the code

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.background}>
        /*<ImageBackground style={styles.background}></ImageBackground>*/
        {/*Header*/}
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../components/YANA.png')}
            style={styles.yana}></Image>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>YANA</Text>
        </View>
        {/*Menu buttons*/}
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Pressable
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('Chatbot');
            }}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../components/chatbot.png')}
              style={styles.buttonImageChat}></Image>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Chatbot</Text>
          </Pressable>

          <Pressable
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('selfCare');
            }}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../components/selfcare.png')}
              style={styles.buttonImage}></Image>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Self-Care</Text>
          </Pressable>

          <Pressable
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('Journal');
            }}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../components/journal.png')}
              style={styles.buttonImage}></Image>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Journal</Text>
          </Pressable>

          {/*Phone and home button*/}
          <Pressable
            style={styles.phone}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('Menu');
            }}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../components/phone.png')}
              style={styles.imgPhone}></Image>
          </Pressable>

          <Pressable
            style={styles.home}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('Splash');
            }}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../components/home.png')}
              style={styles.imgHome}></Image>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add curly braces between the `ImageBackground` Component. React native sees yours as a string so it throws an error that strings must be enclosed within a `Text` tag